# Redux Dev Tools failed to recognize the store configured with Redux-toolkit in React Native App

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit, redux-devtools-extension

Almost all of the questions out there are related to redux middleware but none points to one related to redux-toolkit. As suggested by [this document](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#devtools) I created a store as below

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import cookieReducer from '../features/cookie/cookieSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    cookie: cookieReducer,
  },
  devTools: true, // This should automatically enable Redux DevTools
});

export default store;

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Then I ran the application in debug mode and in 'Redux' dev tools extension tab I do see this!

[image]

I assume the redux toolkit does the auto configuration for Redux Dev Tools as the doc states. Did I miss any additional configuration in code or in Redux Dev Tools configuration ?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Nope. I started using https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger